# Can't see widget areas in my customizer

Tags: widgets, sidebar, theme-customizer, frontpage, register-sidebar

I've registered 7 Sidebars in my template, I can see them correctly in the Apparence > Widget panel and my front-end, but I can't see them in the Theme Customize, when I click on my Widget section I have the following message instead:

> Your theme has 7 widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them.
>   You can navigate to other pages on your site while using the Customizer to view and edit the widgets displayed on those pages.

I'm working with the front-page.php file, and I'm in the front-page of my website. If I work with the index.php I can see my sidebar correctly in the Theme Customizer, also if the code is the same for both the php pages.
Where I'm wrong? 
Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: The message you posted says: `... this particular page doesn’t display them.`
So, in the customizer select/load another page, which displays widgets, and see you see them now. Since 4.0 the customizer can use **Contextual Controls**. `Customizer controls can now be displayed or hidden based on the Customizer’s preview context. For example, options that are only relevant to the front page can be shown only when the user is previewing their front page in the Customizer `. See [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/07/08/customizer-improvements-in-4-0/). Maybe its this.

Comment: I'm in the front-page of my Customizer, I added my sidebars in the front-page php file, and although I can't see my sidebars in the customizer. 
Thank you!

Comment: @valentina.a87 did you ever find a solution for this? I am running into the same issue and can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Hello, yes I've solved the problem at that time, but honestly I can't remember I did I do, also my bad knowledge about php doesn't help you to remember. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1):

**WordPress widgets are context dependent**, that means if any templates use the `dynamic_sidebar()` function or in other words has any sidebar or widget area in that template then you'll see widgets in the customizer. For instance, if `page.php` has sidebar then when you're in a page you'll see widgets in the customizer.

Comment: Thank you to everyone, I'm in the front-page of my Customizer, I added my sidebars in the front-page php file, and although I can't see my sidebars in the customizer.

Comment: @valentina.a87 Check to see if you have an errors in your PHP error log. If the page fails to completely load then the sidebar sections won't activate.